# MongoDB Realm Studio 10.0.0 how to decrypt encrypted database?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm

How do I decrypt my db.realm with the new MongoDB Realm Studio? Typically when i click on the db.realm file, realm studio opens up and it prompts me for the key. The new studio doesn't I get:

> Unable to open a realm at path '/Users/user/Desktop/tdrdb.realm': Realm file initial open failed Path:Exception backtrace:
> 0 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010ef779d1 *ZN5realm15InvalidDatabaseC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9* + 49
> 1 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010ef3a4cd _ZN5realm9SlabAlloc11attach_fileERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEERNS0_6ConfigE + 3453
> 2 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010ef79caa _ZN5realm2DB7do_openERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEbbNS_9DBOptionsE + 3482
> 3 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010ef7cd73 _ZN5realm2DB4openERNS_11ReplicationENS_9DBOptionsE + 243
> 4 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010ef81986 _ZN5realm2DB6createERNS_11ReplicationENS_9DBOptionsE + 342
> 5 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010ea27db5 _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator7open_dbEv + 1277
> 6 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010ea26d42 _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator12do_get_realmENS_5Realm6ConfigERNSt3__110shared_ptrIS2_EENS_4util8OptionalINS_9VersionIDEEERNS8_17CheckedUniqueLockE + 62
> 7 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010ea26ba8 _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator9get_realmENS_5Realm6ConfigENS_4util8OptionalINS_9VersionIDEEE + 530
> 8 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010ea10f8e _ZN5realm5Realm16get_shared_realmENS0_6ConfigE + 128
> 9 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010e8fb1ca _ZN5realm2js10RealmClassINS_4node5TypesEE19create_shared_realmEN4Napi3EnvENS_5Realm6ConfigEbONSt3__13mapINS9_12basic_stringIcNS9_11char_traitsIcEENS9_9allocatorIcEEEENSA_ISG_NS0_9ProtectedINS5_5ValueEEENS9_4lessISG_EENSE_INS9_4pairIKSG_SJ_EEEEEESL_NSE_INSM_ISN_SQ_EEEEEEONSA_ISG_NSH_INS5_8FunctionEEESL_NSE_INSM_ISN_SW_EEEEEE + 234
> 10 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010e8f990e _ZN5realm2js10RealmClassINS_4node5TypesEE11constructorEN4Napi3EnvENS5_6ObjectERNS0_9ArgumentsIS3_EE + 334
> 11 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010e8f6289 _ZN5realm4node10ObjectWrapINS_2js10RealmClassINS0_5TypesEEEE20constructor_callbackERKN4Napi12CallbackInfoE + 135
> 12 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010e8f88da _ZN5realm4node13WrappedObjectINS_2js10RealmClassINS0_5TypesEEEEC2ERKN4Napi12CallbackInfoE + 128
> 13 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010e8f87af *ZZN4Napi10ObjectWrapIN5realm4node13WrappedObjectINS1_2js10RealmClassINS2_5TypesEEEEEE26ConstructorCallbackWrapperEP10napi_env__P20napi_callback_info__ENKUlvE_clEv + 67
> 14 .com.mongodb.realm-studio.ga3lPv 0x000000010e8f8525 *ZN4Napi10ObjectWrapIN5realm4node13WrappedObjectINS1_2js10RealmClassINS2_5TypesEEEEEE26ConstructorCallbackWrapperEP10napi_env__P20napi_callback_info** + 71
> 15 Electron Framework 0x00000001083097ca napi_create_function + 858
> 16 Electron Framework 0x00000001037b62ec _ZN2v88internal9Accessors12MakeAccessorEPNS0_7IsolateENS0_6HandleINS0_4NameEEEPFvNS_5LocalINS_4NameEEERKNS_20PropertyCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEEPFvS9_NS7_ISB_EERKNSA_INS_7BooleanEEEE + 16844
> 17 Electron Framework 0x00000001037b54b8 _ZN2v88internal9Accessors12MakeAccessorEPNS0_7IsolateENS0_6HandleINS0_4NameEEEPFvNS_5LocalINS_4NameEEERKNS_20PropertyCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEEPFvS9_NS7_ISB_EERKNSA_INS_7BooleanEEEE + 13208
> 18 Electron Framework 0x00000001037b4d9f _ZN2v88internal9Accessors12MakeAccessorEPNS0_7IsolateENS0_6HandleINS0_4NameEEEPFvNS_5LocalINS_4NameEEERKNS_20PropertyCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEEPFvS9_NS7_ISB_EERKNSA_INS_7BooleanEEEE + 11391
> 19 Electron Framework 0x00000001041b8999 _ZN2v88internal20SetupIsolateDelegate9SetupHeapEPNS0_4HeapE + 501289.

Comment: Make sure the Realm file format version is compatible between the Realm file and Realm Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please upgrade to MongoDB Realm Studio 10.0.1, which fixes an error when opening an encrypted Realm file https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases